# Why I can't see permission alerts? I configure them on .plist

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, info.plist, alerts

I configure this values, and I. can't see the alerts permissions.

[image]

Comment: Show the code where you request user permission.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please read [ask] to improve your question.

Comment: You have a crucial misunderstanding. These are just explanation texts that will be added to permission alerts. Permission alerts are displayed only when you request permissions by calling relevant methods in your code.

Answer (score 1):

you must do 2 steps to request permissions.

1. Configure Info.plis
2. Request user with code in AppDelegate(or in viewcontroller when you need permission to do something)
3. A sample here: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/cameras_and_media_capture/requesting_authorization_for_media_capture_on_ios